# What does “typedef void (^Something)()” mean

Tags: c++-cli

I was trying to compile [stk](https://github.com/thestk/stk). During the configuration I get the error

> System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:162:2:
>   error: expected identifier or '(' before '^' token 
>   (^AudioObjectPropertyListenerBlock)(

When I see the code I see `^` inside the function pointer declaration at line 162 in [here](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/blob/master/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AudioHardware.h). I know we can have `*` but what does `^` mean?

Code snippet :

```
#if defined(__BLOCKS__)
typedef void
(^AudioObjectPropertyListenerBlock)(    UInt32                              inNumberAddresses,
                                        const AudioObjectPropertyAddress    inAddresses[]);
```

Comment: It means you are not using C++, but C++/CLI, which is Microsoft's bastardisation of C++ and something you don't normally want to be using.

Comment: Nothing to do with C++/CLI (note "MacOSX-SDKs"), it is okay when Apples does it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912023/caret-in-objective-c

Comment: Objective-C is not C; Objective-C++ is not C++.  Whatever file you are compiling is include an Objective-C header file, so the source needs to be compiled as Objective-C or Objective-C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answerers here say, it could be in C++/CLI.

But also, if you are on a macOS (like you hinted in one comment), this is an ***Objective-C block***.

Its syntax is very very weird.

The block is like a C++ closures and Java anonymous inner classes, it can capture variables.

```
__block int insider = 0;

void(^block)() = ^{
    // print insider here using your favourite method,  printf for example
};
```

This is a complete `NSObject` (base Objective-C class), but is callable, this is not a mere function pointer.

Refer to this Apple document: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Now, we go to the important question, I want to run this on Linux, how ???

LLVM supports block syntax, but you should refer to this StackOverflow question for more: [Clang block in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907071/clang-block-in-linux/11097610#11097610)

So, you should compile your code in the LLVM compiler, and use -fblocks and -lBlocksRuntime.

Don't forget to install those Linux packages:

llvm
clang
libblocksruntime-dev

If you are already on macOS,  just use -fblocks.

Comment: Yes adding ` -fblocks` and `-lBlocksRuntime` did the trick.